# Data to Userdefault encoder class for storing custom object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsuserdefaults, encode

Can anyone give me any link or file, which could be used globally for a project to Store data to `NSUserDefault`.
Which contains method to save dictionary, array,string,integer all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below link, You will get thing which you need..

[NSUserDefaults](https://github.com/pcperini/NSUserDefaults-Convenience)

Answer (score 1):

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "BSUser.h"


@interface CLServerDataManager : NSObject

+(BOOL) saveServerDataToUserDefaults:(id)data;
+(NSDictionary*) getServerDataFromUserDefaults;

//For language Selection
+(void) setLanguage:(NSString*)LanguageName;
+(NSString*) getLanguage;



+(void) setUserPassword:(NSString*)password;
+(NSString*) getUserPassword;

+(void) setUserID:(NSString*)password;
+(NSString*) getUserID;

+(void) setUserUUID:(NSString*)uuid;
+(NSString*) getUserUUID;


+(void) setUserName:(NSString*)name;
+(NSString*) getUserName;

+(void) setimagedata:(float)data;
+(float) getimagedata;


+(void) setUserProfile:(BSUser*)user;
+(BSUser*) getUserProfile;

+ (void) setApplicationPurchaseStatus:(BOOL)purchaseStatus forUser:(NSString*)fbUserID;
+ (BOOL) getApplicationPurchaseStatusforUser:(NSString*)fbUserID;


+ (void) sethintAndTutorial:(BOOL)hintState;

+ (BOOL) gethintAndtutorial;


+ (void) setDeviceToken:(NSString*)deviceToken;
+ (NSString*) getDeviceToken;


//Methods for clear all data from user defaults
+ (void) resetServerDataManager;
@end
```

and .m file for this

```
#import "CLServerDataManager.h"
#import "ClConfig.h"

@implementation CLServerDataManager

+(BOOL) saveServerDataToUserDefaults:(id)data {
//    if (!data) {
//        return NO;
//    }
//    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//  [defaults setObject:data forKey:USER_ID];
//  [defaults synchronize];
//    return YES;
    return NO;

}

+(NSDictionary*) getServerDataFromUserDefaults {
//    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//  NSDictionary* rememberMe = [defaults objectForKey:USER_ID];
//    if (rememberMe == nil) {
//        return nil;
//    }
//  return rememberMe;
    return nil;
}


//For the store user select language and again fetch
+(void) setLanguage:(NSString*)LanguageName {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:LanguageName forKey:@"Language"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}

+(NSString*) getLanguage {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* Mylanguage = [defaults objectForKey:@"Language"];
    if (Mylanguage == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    return Mylanguage;
}


//for store information cache for user's pics download
+(void) setimagedata:(float)data{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:data] forKey:@"cache"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}
+(float)getimagedata{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    float data = [[defaults objectForKey:@"cache"] floatValue];
    if (data == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return data;

}



+(void) setUserPassword:(NSString*)password {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+(NSString*) getUserPassword {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* rememberMe = [defaults objectForKey:@"password"];
    if (rememberMe == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    return rememberMe;

}

+(void) setUserID:(NSString*)password {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:password forKey:@"userID"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+(NSString*) getUserID {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* rememberMe = [defaults objectForKey:@"userID"];
    if (rememberMe == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    return rememberMe;
}

+(void) setUserUUID:(NSString*)uuid {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:uuid forKey:@"userUUID"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+(NSString*) getUserUUID {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* rememberMe = [defaults objectForKey:@"userUUID"];
    if (rememberMe == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    return rememberMe;
}


+(void) setUserName:(NSString*)name {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:name forKey:@"userName"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+(NSString*) getUserName {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* name = [defaults objectForKey:@"userName"];
    if (name == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    return name;
}

//store the current login user profile to user defaults

+(void) setUserProfile:(BSUser*)user {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:user] forKey:@"user_profile"];
    [defaults synchronize];

}


+(BSUser*) getUserProfile {
    BSUser* returnObject = nil;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSData *dataRepresentingSavedArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"user_profile"];
    if (dataRepresentingSavedArray != nil)
    {
        returnObject = (BSUser*)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataRepresentingSavedArray];
    }
    return returnObject;
}





+ (void) setApplicationPurchaseStatus:(BOOL)purchaseStatus forUser:(NSString*)fbUserID {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:purchaseStatus] forKey:fbUserID];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+ (BOOL) getApplicationPurchaseStatusforUser:(NSString*)fbUserID {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber* purchased = [defaults objectForKey:fbUserID];
    if (purchased == nil) {
        return NO;
    }
    return [purchased boolValue];
}


#pragma mark Set hint and tutotrial
+ (void) sethintAndTutorial:(BOOL)hintState{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:hintState] forKey:@"hint"];

    [defaults synchronize];

}

+ (BOOL) gethintAndtutorial{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber* hintstate = [defaults objectForKey:@"hint"];

    if (hintstate == nil) {
        return NO;
    }
    return [hintstate boolValue];
}



+ (void) setDeviceToken:(NSString*)deviceToken {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:deviceToken forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

+ (NSString*) getDeviceToken {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* name = [defaults objectForKey:@"DeviceToken"];
    if (name == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    return name;
}

+ (void) resetServerDataManager {

    [[self class] setLanguage:nil];

    [[self class] setUserID:nil];
    [[self class] setUserName:nil];
    [[self class] setUserPassword:nil];
    [[self class] setUserProfile:nil];
    [[self class] setUserUUID:nil];

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString *domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
}
```